# access denied when getting personal site (JSOM)

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

I am trying to get my blog posts by using JSOM, following is my code to get personal_site/blog which generates "unexpected response data from server", when I debug the JavaScript it shows "Access Denied". (my personal site located on another web application).

```
  bolagContext = new SP.ClientContext(url);

  var oList = bolagContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Posts');

  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy></Query><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' /><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' /><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' /><RowLimit>2</RowLimit></View>');
  collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

  bolagContext.load(collListItem);

  bolagContext.executeQueryAsync(
  Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

   //go through items
  }),
Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {

  alert(args.get_message()); // says: unexpected response data from server".
}
```

I have tested the code to get another list on another site and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSOM only works within the scope of a site collection.  To fetch data from a different web application you'll have to use the REST interface or Lists.asmx and pass your credentials along with the request.

Comment: thank you, now I am using REST when I run my query on browswer it works but it generates this error in my javascript code.
Error: Invalid field or parameter requestInfo.url. I am not using apps usual javascript file and var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

Comment: ask a new question, post your code to it, and explain what you're expecting, and what you're getting.